# Examples of analytic aposteriority vs. the erotetic demarcation of analytic/synthetic knowledge

Tags: analytic-synthetic-divide

[In another post here](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/72716/can-the-analytic-synthetic-distinction-be-accounted-for-as-an-erotetic-differenc), I asked whether the analytic/synthetic distinction could be grounded in/reframed as an erotetic distinction. So assuming that grounding/reframing in the background as 'given' (if only for the sake of argument), I now would like to ask whether any of the following cases involves analytic knowledge *a posteriori*. Their template is the idea of "self-answering questions," i.e. wh-questions whose predominant wh-term is "solved for" by the entire question being "fed back into" the original erotetic function. (Historical precedents/precursors with which I am familiar include Smullyman's *What Is the Name of This Book?*, Quine's, "Yields falsehood when preceded by its own quotation," and (though by conceptual happenstance) the, "Speak, friend, and enter," riddle from *The Fellowship of the Ring*.)

> 1. Imagine there is an artificially sentient door that has been programmed to open only if it is asked a specific question. So there is a natural inquiry along the lines of, "What question, when asked, opens this door?" or, poetically, "What is the key to this door?" Suppose, then, that some question like this (perhaps in a different language or even arbitrarily many languages) is what the door was programmed to respond to by opening itself. In that event, the question is its own answer, and the very act of asking the question in front of the door will unwittingly open it. So is *"What is the key to this door?" is the key to this door* known analytically *a posteriori*?

> 2. *?Mμɑϝ ᴉƨ ϝμԍ dnԍƨϝᴉou ϝμɑϝ λon ɑʁԍ ʁԍɑqᴉuმ ʁᴉმμϝ uoʍ nbƨᴉqԍ-qoʍu ᴉu ɑ wᴉʁʁoʁƾ* Chances are, if you've taken the time to resolve this one, you're standing in front of a mirror with a phone or a tablet or a laptop in hand, held upside-down. Or you're a lexical virtuoso who can flip and fold the alphabet in your head. Does that mean that the question, when it is its own correct answer, is only contingently so? But then, if this is also a matter of analytic aposteriority, have we uncovered a *contingent* analytic truth? (Or: when read via mental flipping and folding, is the question then apprehended *a priori*, to the further effect that it is not only contingent whether the question is its own answer, but whether its answer is known *a priori*? For when mentally reconfigured, the question is no longer its own answer, although there might be another question, "What is the question that you just reconfigured in your visual imagination?" that serves our earlier purpose, here... **Or what about: "What is the question that you are reading in a mirror right now OR that you just flipped and folded in your head?"**)

Comment: Gödel thought in a somewhat Kantian way that human reason would be fatally irrational if it asked questions it could not answer, so if this is true then every question asked by a rational human being seems intrinsically necessarily erotetic and reading such a question in a mirror is not some contingent posterior truth, but only some truth bearer token in all possible worlds with humans...

Comment: @DoubleKnot, it would be contingent whether one read the question in a mirror, though. Like, you might see the upside-down/reversed symbols and think, "I'm not wasting my time on this," and leave it at that. Or you might read the question by flipping it in your mind. But then the correct answer to, "What question am I reading in a mirror?" is, "Nothing is the question I am reading in a mirror." So if there is a context where the question would not be its own correct answer, it seems contingent that the question correctly answers itself.

Comment: @RodolfoAP, the 'endgame' of my defense of analytic knowledge is an opinion about the paradox of conceptual analysis. The idea is that treating 'correct' analyses of individual concepts as informative is not what is at stake; rather, there is a higher-order question, "Which concepts are unanalyzable?" that is served by the process of conceptual analysis.

Comment: Following the Kantian framework of ideas, there's a precise logic in the synthetic a posteriori, but not on the analytic a posteriori. In addition, if you exceed such framework of thinking, I think you need to reframe the goal of this erotetic demarcation you propose. As such, the answer would require several subjective assumptions. For example: yes, both. Or, none. (comment reposted due to typo a-priori x a-posteriori).

Comment: Some legend was told once upon a time some irrational mad person saw his own head in the mirror thought it was someone else's, and suddenly worried about the location of his own head and ran around to ask every person he met where's his head. So seems to me irrational human being may be contingently affected by mirroring, but for rational people with such a mirror or not doesn't affect truth value of any erotetic answerable question or propositional...

Comment: Consider, "Ի՞նչ հարց ես հենց նոր հայերենից թարգմանել" If you did translate it from Armenian just then, it answered itself correctly; but if you read it *in* Armenian, it isn't its own correct answer as such, is it? I don't see an irrationality issue, here, in the alleged contingency...

Comment: Though to be sure, in my system, issues with defining erotetic powersets vs. the (*S*?) function (the answer function, which takes a question for its input and tries to list all *possibly correct* answers to it) complicate this question of saying that the above questions do or do not have given correct answers on specific occasions.

Comment: If your just say in English "What question are you just asking" after Armenian "Ի՞նչ հարց ես հենց նոր հայերենից թարգմանել", and magically a door somewhere is opened, I can argue what it answers is not the original question but some cryptic version of it. So any question can be interpreted in many ways including light and extremely cryptic ways. But at least for the learned and rational people understand both English and Armenian, the apparent erotetic question is answered *a priori* at worlds with English and Armenian languages, my utterance is just a bearer token whose existence is possible..

Comment: For an Armenian mystic upon hearing "Ի՞նչ հարց ես հենց նոր հայերենից թարգմանել", s/he may reflect and answer totally differently semantically in their own idiosyncratic cryptic ways only possible in *a posteriori* way, it may be interpreted as "What question are you *really* asking, or "What question are *you* really asking", for example...